# Convert Titanium Application into Module

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I have implemented Pull to refresh functionality in my android application, its works fine. Now I want to convert this functionality as a module. How can I do this?,Thanks in advance. I am using Titanium SDK 1.8 and Android 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to rewrite it all in java. the current SDK for android does not support javascript modules

Answer (score 0):

follow the link, could help you...

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/36711/how-to-create-a-module-in-xcode-with-a-view-for-titanium-mobile